# How to deny class visibility from external application?

Tags: java, android, class

I want to allow visibility within the package as seen in the image, I want Class1 from Package1 to be able to see Class2 from Package2 (Subpackage of Package1), also I want the external Class0 to be able to see Class1 from Package1, but not to be able to see Class2 from Package2(Subpackage).

[image]

In resume C0 can only see C1 and C1 can only see C2. C0 can't see C2 directly.

C = Class,
P = Package

Best regards.

Comment: subpackage don't have any impact on visibility :  a subpackage is "just another package". What do you mean by "external App" (an App that you didn't wrote must be able to call something in C1 ?)

Comment: What is P1? A JAR? An Android library project? Just some Java classes in the app's directory tree? Something else? Also, what do you mean by "see"?

Comment: There are two Apps side-by-side (App1)-(App2 (P1(C1)(P2(C2)(C3)))). P = Package, C = Class, "See" as in visibility access control.

Comment: If they are independent apps, App1 has no access to anything from App2, except perhaps via some IPC mechanism that you offer.

Comment: @CommonsWare You don't seem to be trying to answer my question. In Android Studio you can import several apps within one app as libraries or full projects or whatever you like. Yet my question does not go to that extent and only involves upward visibility from classes.

Comment: "You don't seem to be trying to answer my question" -- that is because your question does not make sense to me. "In Android Studio you can import several apps within one app as libraries or full projects or whatever you like" -- neither your question, nor this comment, indicates whether or not this is actually what you are doing. You are certainly welcome to edit your question and provide more details regarding your build environment and the nature of these apps, and perhaps somebody can help you.

Comment: @CommonsWare It may have seen confusing to describe an App as an element accessing my package, so I simplify my explanation by changing the App to a Class0, which represents any class external from Package1. Also I've added the visibility that I don't want to be available, marked with a red cross. I hope this satisfy you and clears any future doubt.